# Want to fix HP Proliant G8 DL360P "Fan Solution Not Sufficient" error instead of spending $100 for the replacement

Tags: hp-proliant, fan

I have a G8 DL360P at datacenter. Few days ago, it stopped booting with an error of Fan Solution Not Sufficient.

I logged in to the iLO and found Fan Block 4 and 6 are degraded.

I already upgraded to the newest firmware/bios and searched up about it for few hours and tried to disable thermal shutdown on the BIOS but the error & shutdown happen before I can get into BIOS

Is there any way to fix this problem with KVM (IPMI/iLO) instead of buying new fans and spend like $100 for remote hands…

Comment: You buy the new fans. This isn't the sort of thing you skimp on.

Answer (score 4):

The fans (654752-001) are [~$10 each](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=654752-001%20&_sacat=0&_sop=15).

It would behoove you to replace the failed units.
You can flip the BIOS option to allow operations with reduced fan count *after* you replace the fans.

DL360p Gen8 servers tend to lose these fans as they age. I keep 20 spare fans on hand at my datacenter because of this.

Your remote hands pricing and support needs were probably known at the time of co-locating the system, so that's a cost you have to plan for. $100 remote hands is better than an un-bootable server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  I decided to buy new fans and pay for the remote hands fee.

Comment: And here I am in the same situation today at a customer's remote datacenter... Karma :)